# Create Folder depends on ID , upload images , and save the path in database in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, model-view-controller, file-upload

i am work in Property Project that allow system user when add Property upload Images for it . what i need to doing create folder depends on ID of property ,save the path in database and uploaded the images in this folder .

i create in my Property model :

```
public string Images { get; set; }
```

in View i create :

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label"> choose image   </label>
                            <input multiple type="file" title="choose image" id="files" name="PropImage" onchange="show(this)" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                </div>
```

my JavaScript :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleFileSelect() {
            //Check File API support
            if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {

                var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
                var output = document.getElementById("result");

                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    var file = files[i];
                    //Only pics
                    if (!file.type.match('image')) continue;

                    var picReader = new FileReader();
                    picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                        var picFile = event.target;
                        var div = document.createElement("div");
                        div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" + "title='" + picFile.name + "'/>";
                        output.insertBefore(div, null);
                    });
                    //Read the image
                    picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

now in my controller i cant create folder because the ID of property not created yet , how i can do ? and should i have  permissions to create folder ?

my controller :

public ActionResult CreateProperties(AddPropertyViewModel model,
            List PropImage)
        {

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            foreach (var item in PropImage)
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~\ImgUp\" /*+ PropImagefolderName*/), item.FileName);//+ IdentityImageFolderName)
                item.SaveAs(path);

            }

            //model.PropertiesVM.ID = properToAdd.PropAddress.Id;
            // string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName); //getting file name without extension  
            // string myfile = name + "_" + properToAdd.ID + ext; //appending the name with id  
            // store the file inside ~/project folder(Img) 
            var imagepath = Server.MapPath(PropImageDirctory);
            //var IdentityPath = Server.MapPath(IdentityImageDirctory);
            properToAdd.Images = imagepath;
            properToAdd.Build_area = model.PropertiesVM.Build_area;
            properToAdd.Earth_area = model.PropertiesVM.Earth_area;
            properToAdd.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
            properToAdd.Prop_Type_ID = Prop_type_ID;
            properToAdd.Plate_ID = plateID;
            properToAdd.Branch_ID = BranshID;
            properToAdd.Price = model.PropertiesVM.Price;
            properToAdd.AddedBy = FullName; /*currentUserName;*/

            db.D_Properties.Add(properToAdd);

            //IdentityImage.SaveAs(Path.Combine(IdentityFolderPath, IdentityImageFileName));
            // InstrumentImage.SaveAs(Path.Combine(IdentityPath, InstrumentImageFileName));
            db.SaveChanges();
            TypesDropDownList();
            PlatesDropDownList();
            BranchesDropDownList();
            TempData["noti"] = "Success";
            return RedirectToAction("CreateProperties");
        }

            //ViewBag.message = "Please choose only Image file";
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form  
            TypesDropDownList();
            PlatesDropDownList();
            BranchesDropDownList();
            TempData["noti"] = "Error";
        return View();

    }
```

Comment: Who generates the property id? The database is my guess. You need to write it to database in order to retrieve the id - and that is not a problem since you need no further info to "create" the property. Retrieving the generated id can be done in the same operation as the database insert - whether you're using Entity Framework or not. Please add further details to your post.

Comment: yes id generate from database . you mean after save change method i can get current id  ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Write your controller action without retrieving the id, edit your post and add the controller's definition and then we'll show you how to retrieve the id.

Comment: i updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Property` class (or whatever type `properToAdd` is) has an `id` property that is properly defined, once you call `db.SaveChanges();` the object `properToAdd`'s id will contain the new database record id - problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to upload images by `ajax` or whatever before saving properties details it means still you are not assigning any id for new records then in my view you can do as following.

1. you have `tempImgs` folder on server. rename file to $_SESSION['userid']+i
2. when submiting property record
3. get the new submitted record ID.
4. create directory like `'../uploads/'+<<new record id>>`
5. move file from `tempImgs` to the new created folder

hope this answers to your concern